# Change wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label function in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

Inside Woocommerce plugin on the `includes` subfolder, there's a file `wc-cart-functions.php`. 
I would like to change the function `wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label()`, but I am not allowed to copy the function to my theme's functions.php. I believe I have to use a custom action/filter to change this core function, but no idea how to do that.

**Original function:**

```
function wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) {
    $label     = $method->get_label();
    $has_cost  = 0 < $method->cost;
    $hide_cost = ! $has_cost && in_array( $method->get_method_id(), array( 'free_shipping', 'local_pickup' ), true );

    if ( $has_cost && ! $hide_cost ) {
        if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() );
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && ! wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
                $label .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        } else {
            $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost );
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
                $label .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        }
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', $label, $method );
}
```

**What the function should be:**

```
function wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) {
    $label     = $method->get_label();
    $has_cost  = 0 < $method->cost;
    $hide_cost = ! $has_cost && in_array( $method->get_method_id(), array( 'free_shipping', 'local_pickup' ), true );

    if ( $has_cost && ! $hide_cost ) {
        if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() );
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && ! wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
                $label .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        } else {
            $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost );
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
                $label .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        }
    }
    /* Here's the code I want added */
    elseif ( ! $has_cost && ! $hide_cost ) {
        $label .= ': Free';
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', $label, $method );
}
```

**What I want to do:**
Shipping methods that have zero cost should have "Free" added to their label. Right now there's nothing shown beside the method title.

How can I make the necessary changes to this function, without overwriting Woocommerce core files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see in this function you can use `woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label` filter hook, to manage that change, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'change_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 );
function change_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) {
    $has_cost  = 0 < $method->cost;
    $hide_cost = ! $has_cost && in_array( $method->get_method_id(), array( 'free_shipping', 'local_pickup' ), true );

    if ( ! $has_cost && ! $hide_cost ) {
        $label  = $method->get_label() . ': Free';
    }
    return $label;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you it works. The part that gets me confusing is I always thought "actions" are what you add if custom code needs to be added to an existing function.

Comment: @DanishMuneer You can "hook into" functions with the help of actions within WordPress. This has the advantage that when you update for example WooCommerce, that your code is still there because it's written into your functions.php file which never get's overridden with an update - instead of the plugin. The way Loic did this, is 100 % correct and state of the art. So if it helped you, you have to check the answer as correct.

Comment: @Mr.Jo This is what my code does, It uses a filter hook, instead of overwriting core files and this is the purpose of this question too.