# Hide costs from available shipping methods options In WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

Is it possible to hide WooCommerce available shipping options costs on cart page?
I would like to display costs only on the checkout page.

On the screenshot below, the costs are underlined in red:

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The follwing will remove shipping costs from shipping options in cart only:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 );
function filter_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) {
    // On cart remove costs 
    if( is_cart() ) {
       return $method->get_label();
    }
    return $label;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Change wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label function in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464772/change-wc-cart-totals-shipping-method-label-function-in-woocommerce/55464799#55464799)

Comment: Hi Loic, I've tried and it didn't work. It shows that the website has a critic error. :/