# Customize Shipping Label from WooCommerce Cart and Checkout Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I want to remove the shipping label value in the cart and checkout pages when the value get assigned to shipping. Ex:- Change ' flat rate 100.00$ ' to ' 100.00$ ' . That means i just want the value without label text. Could you please help me to achieve this?

I have changed as `$rates[$targeted_rate_id]->label = '';` in the shipping_package_rates_filter_callback function. but it is still showing ' : ' (colon symbol) at the start of the value. Ex:- **:100.00$** .

**shipping_package_rates_filter_callback**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_package_rates_filter_callback', 100, 2 );
function shipping_package_rates_filter_callback( $rates, $package ) {
    // HERE define your targeted rate id
    $targeted_rate_id = 'flat_rate:4'; 
    
    if ( ! array_key_exists($targeted_rate_id, $rates) ) 
        return $rates;
    
    $new_cost = WC()->session->get('shipping_cost'); // Get new cost from WC sessions

    if ( ! empty($new_cost) ) {
        // Set shipping label empty
        $rates[$targeted_rate_id]->label = '';
        $rate = $rates[$targeted_rate_id];
        $cost = $rate->cost; // Set the initial cost in a variable for taxes calculations
        $rates[$targeted_rate_id]->cost = $new_cost; // Set the new cost

        $has_taxes = false; // Initializing
        $taxes     = array(); // Initializing
        foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax_cost){
            if( $tax_cost > 0 ) {
                $tax_rate    = $tax_cost / $cost; // Get the tax rate conversion
                $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate; // Set the new tax cost in taxes costs array
                $has_taxes   = true; // There are taxes (set it to true)
            }
        }
        if( $has_taxes ) {
            $rates[$targeted_rate_id]->taxes = $taxes; // Set taxes costs array
        }
    } else {
        unset($rates[$targeted_rate_id]);
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the colon symbol `": "` from a displayed shipping method, use the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'display_only_shipping_method_price', 10, 2 );
function display_only_shipping_method_price( $label, $method ) {
    // HERE define your targeted rate id
    $targeted_rate_id = 'flat_rate:4';

    if ( $method->id === $targeted_rate_id && 0 < $method->cost ) {
        $label = str_replace( $method->label . ': ', '', $label);
    }
    return $label;
}
```

Related:

- [Change WooCommerce Checkout shipping method cost from a WC Session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77952208/change-woocommerce-checkout-shipping-method-cost-from-a-wc-session-variable/77954335#77954335)
- [Change wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label function in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464772/change-wc-cart-totals-shipping-method-label-function-in-woocommerce/55464799#55464799)